# Windows form designer, NumericUpDown not containing a definition

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

So I'm getting this error

`'dicegui.MainForm' does not contain a definition for 'DiceNumericValueChanged' and no extension method 'DiceNumericValueChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'dicegui.MainForm' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) - C:\Users\b\Documents\Projects\dicegui\dicegui\MainForm.Designer.cs:90,66`

for two numericupdowns that I'm trying to take a value from. I'm not entirely sure why. Was hoping someone would be able to give me a clue as to whats going on. It's a pretty basic windows form program and I haven't changed too much.

This is mymainform.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dicegui
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

        int maxDice;
        int diceType;
        Random _r =new Random();

        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
        }

        void RollButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            maxDice = (int) diceNumeric.Value;
            diceType = (int) sidesNumeric.Value;

            DiceLoop();
        }

        public int RandomDice()
        {
            int n = _r.Next (1, diceType);
            return n;
        }

        public void DiceLoop()
        {
            int result = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < maxDice; i++)
            {
                result += RandomDice();
            }
            string resultS = Convert.ToString(result);
            //MessageBox.Show("You rolled " + result);
        }

    }
}
```

my program.cs is all stock

and this is the areas where the errors are in the MainForm.Designer.cs

```
    this.diceNumeric.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 75);
    this.diceNumeric.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] {
                            1,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0});
    this.diceNumeric.Name = "diceNumeric";
    this.diceNumeric.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(69, 22);
    this.diceNumeric.TabIndex = 3;
    this.diceNumeric.Value = new decimal(new int[] {
                            1,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0});
    this.diceNumeric.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.DiceNumericValueChanged);
    // 
    // sidesNumeric
    // 
    this.sidesNumeric.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(172, 74);
    this.sidesNumeric.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] {
                            2,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0});
    this.sidesNumeric.Name = "sidesNumeric";
    this.sidesNumeric.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(63, 22);
    this.sidesNumeric.TabIndex = 4;
    this.sidesNumeric.Value = new decimal(new int[] {
                            2,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0});
    this.sidesNumeric.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.SidesNumericValueChanged);
```

Yeah I don't have a clue whats going on here I havent modified anything in the mainform.designer.cs file at all so it seems to me like it should be working.

Comment: Does your form class contain a method definition for `DiceNumericValueChanged` with the expected signature? This method isn't in any of your code snippets included in the question.

Comment: @M.Babcock is correct, all that error is saying is that you are trying to call `DiceNumericValueChanged` but a method of that name doesnt exist in the scope.

Comment: Probably not. I'm not sure where that would go or why it would be missing however. I've done tutorials with numericupdowns in them before and haven't had to add a numericvaluechanged method in. I'm assuming its usually generated by the windowsformdesigner. I'm not sure why its different for this program. I guess I'll go through the mainform.designer.cs file for one of the tutorials I did and try to find an example of that method.

Comment: Check out my answer.  If you dont care about the dice value changing, then just remove the line in the designer.cs file

Comment: Also, instead of finding an example of that method.. just use intelisense.  If you type the `+=` after `.ValueChanged`, then hit tab twice, it will build all of it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DiceNumericValueChanged` to your main form.

```
void DiceNumericValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some logic about the dice changing
}
```

You are calling the method here:

```
this.diceNumeric.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.DiceNumericValueChanged);
```

But there is no reference to it in "this"  ("this" being all the partials of mainform)

If you dont want to do anything when the Dice Numeric Value changes, then you can just delete the reference line from the designer.

Comment: THANKS!! This was totally the problem. The windowsform designer had autogenerated that method and I didn't need it at all. I commented it out and the whole program works great now. Thank you :)